# How to configure in-memory unit testing of ASP.NET Web Api 2 OData service?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, odata, in-memory

[This article](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/asp-net-web-api-integration-testing-with-in-memory-hosting/) presents an elegant way of in-memory testing ASP.NET Web API sites: an instance of HttpClient is created using HttpServer as a constructor argument, and after that client's requests are executed from within the same process.

I am trying to achieve the same but with OData service. I compiled a sample OData service using ASP.NET Web Api 2 OData classes, generated service reference in the client project (and referenced the Web site project), but the test code doesn't communicate with the OData service. This is the code:

```
    var ctx = new Container(new Uri("http://www.myservice.com/"));
    CollectionAssert.IsNotEmpty(ctx.Products);
```

I can see that it's making an in-memory call into the container Web site, but it doesn't reach the OData service. Am I missing some configuration trick?

Comment: What version of .net are you running on the server? What are you using to host Web API? HttpServer + .net 4.0? Try upgrading to .net 4.5 and use OWin instead. I spent an entire night trying to get it work with that combo, and in the end I had to fall back to IIS...

Comment: I am using .net 4.5 and host using IIS (IIS Express in fact but that shouldn't matter since I am trying to host in-memory). I didn't try OWIN, just tried to use the solution described in the article and it works for HttpClient requests but not when I try to consume the OData feed.

Comment: Try OWin hosting. The example uses HttpServer and NOT IIS. That is not supported anymore, take a look at nuget. What you call in memory hosting is usually called self hosting, self as in without iis. Web API runs at a lower level than MVC.